# Allocating the timevalue from a cell entry

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I am trying to make sub's in vba to repeat a process processC after some time
as designated in the Cell K8 = 00:10:00 (text format).

```
Dim RunTimer As Date

Sub repeatA()
    'RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    RunTimer = Now + TimeValue(K8)
    Application.OnTime RunTimer, "repeatB"
End Sub

Sub repeatB()
    call processC
    call repeatA
End Sub

Sub processC()
    ...
End Sub
```

It works fine when I use `RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")`, but when I tried as above I got below error message. I want to assign "00:10:00" from a cell K8 entry.
[image]

Comment: Look into your data types. Basically `Time` is a very precise fraction of 1. Therefore it requires a value of Double datatype. `Date` on the other hand is an integer. `Dim RunTimer As Date` is asking for trouble. When you enter "00:10:00" in a cell that is a string. `TimeValue("00:10:00")` would convert it to a Double. You can see the value in the Immediate Window with Debug.Print TimeValue(Range("K8").Value). Format K8 as Time and then enter a value in the format your system recognizes as Time and there should be no problem reading it into a variable of Double data type.

Comment: Sub repeatA() / 

    Dim val As Variant / 

    val = TimeValue(Range("K8").Value / 

    RunTimer = Now + val / 

    Application.OnTime RunTimer, "repeatB" / 

End Sub / 


I keep the format of K8 as text (K8=00:10:00), and the above modification solved the problem. Thanx for your prompt advice.

Comment: correction, val = TimeValue(Range("K8").Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't type **Range** which is probably your main issue. It also matters if your cell's value is *numeric* or *text*.

### Numeric Examples

In this example below, I have typed `00:10:00` this into the cell (no equals sign). Excel converts this to decimal (`.0069444` -- essentially the percentage of a full day). The display may be the decimal or a time such as `12:10:00 AM`. Regardless this is a *numeric* value that does not need to be converted with VBA.

Another numeric situation would be if the cell formula was: `=TIMEVALUE("00:10:00")` which converts exactly to the same `.0069444`.

All numeric situation should work with this VBA code:

`RunTimer = Now + Range("K8").Value`

[image: Numeric entry]

### Text Examples

If your cell is actually *text* with formulas/displays such as:

- `="00:10:00"`
- `'00:10:00"`

Then you SHOULD use your TimeValue Vba method:
`RunTimer = Now + TimeValue(Range("K8").Value)`

[image: text entry]

### Test if *Numeric* or *Text*

You could also try to make it dynamic by testing using [isNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) (though this might have some issues, depending on excel file)

```
If IsNumeric(Range("K8")) Then
    RunTimer = Now + Range("K8").Value

Else
    RunTimer = Now + TimeValue(Range("K8"))

End If
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: works fine for the second solution, but still not sure about the first solution.

Comment: @HeuigiSon I spent some time improving the answer. If it still doesn't work, would you mind posting a screenshot of your cell in your question? If it does, I'd be most grateful if you clicked the `Accept` check. Thanks. 

Comment: Thankfully accepted. Thanx for your time and kind advice.